# GTK3 C Menu button with Popover menu sample code (ONLY using .c, not .ui)

Tags: c, button, gtk3, popover

How I can get working simple gtk_menu_button_new() with gtk_popover_menu_new()?
When I tried that using Glade, it worked flawlessly, however, I need .c code, not .ui code. 
I can't find single sample code on the internet that uses only .c for Popovermenu

Can someone provide very simple example code where popover menu contains few buttons? Preferably, where window design code is written in int main, not static void activate.

[There will be .gif that will show what I want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZjU6.gif)

P.S. I am aware, that in order to fit multiple buttons inside, I need to use GTK_BOX.

EDIT: I have added sample code, which contains Menu button, but it doesn't work. Please, finish this code to work like in .gif.
Compilation: gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o './testprogram.run' './testprogramcode.c' `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`

Edit 2: I added one button to testBox

Code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

    GtkWidget *window;


    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    //Create window
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 200);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Simple menu");


    //Creating fixed container
    GtkWidget *fixedContainer = gtk_fixed_new ();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), fixedContainer);

    //Creating and adding new menu button in fixed container
    GtkWidget *testMenuButton = gtk_menu_button_new ();
    gtk_fixed_put (GTK_FIXED(fixedContainer), testMenuButton, 50, 50);

    //Adding popover to menu button
    GtkWidget *testPopOver = gtk_popover_new (testMenuButton);

    //Creating GTK_BOX to hold popover box contents
    GtkWidget *testBox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);

    //Creating and adding new button in testBox
    GtkWidget *testButton = gtk_button_new ();
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(testBox), testButton, TRUE, TRUE, 5);

    //How to add testBox to testPopOver?









    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you like the `.ui` file? You can include it directly into your C program if you don't want to rely on external files.

Comment: I am avoiding .ui files, because it wastes computer resources more, than just directly putting gui objects without middleman (I assume, that .ui is midleman). I am doing everything, what I can do to program work as fast as possible even if I make program development time longer. If I have choice between fast and little bit faster, I choose little bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this snippet:

```
  GtkWidget *mb = gtk_menu_button_new ();
  GtkWidget *po = gtk_popover_new (mb);
  GtkWidget *lb = gtk_label_new ("hello");

  gtk_container_add (po, lb);
  g_object_set (mb, "margin", 150, NULL);
  gtk_menu_button_set_popover (mb, po);
```

However, avoiding .ui is being penny-wise. You'd better avoid premature optimisations.

Comment: I tried to implement this, but it didn't work. Can you please take the code above and try to finish it? I made that very short code to be clear as possible to solve this problem. I am new to GTK3 and C, maybe I made mistake implementing it.

Comment: @Bumbieris112 your testBox is empty, add at least one widget there.

Comment: I did as you told. But I am still stuck. Do not know how to add testBox to testPopOver.

Comment: @Bumbieris112 `gtk_container_add` (line 5 in my code). GtkPopover is GtkBin's subclass.

Comment: I already tried that several times. I can't get it working. Could you please try yourself?

Comment: @Bumbieris112 try calling `gtk_widget_show_all` on popover.